# How to calculate the center of ngmap polygon?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-map

I am using ngmap and whenever i import KML polygon file the polygon is drown on the map.
I have an issue concerning zooming on the polygon. 
Is there any way to calculate the polygon center (lattitude and longitude) ?
if not is there anyway to zoom on the polygon after drawing it on the ngmap.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Whenever KML layer is added and the `preserve-viewport` attribute of `kml-layer` directive is set to `true`, the map is automatically getting centered based on layer viewport (it also means there is no need to specify the center explicitly)

To determine KML layer center:

1) set `id` attribute of `kml-layer` directive to reference KML Layer

```
<kml-layer preserve-viewport="true" id="myLayer" url="http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml"></kml-layer>
```

2) once the layer is rendered, get the instance of KML layer and then the center via `google.maps.KmlLayer.getDefaultViewport` function:

```
NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
        var layer = map.kmlLayers["myLayer"]
        var center = layer.getDefaultViewport().getCenter();       
});
```

Example

```js
angular.module('mapApp', ['ngMap'])
    .controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, NgMap) {

        NgMap.getMap().then(function(map) {
            $scope.map = map;
            var layer = map.kmlLayers["myLayer"]
            var center = layer.getDefaultViewport().getCenter();
            console.log(center.toString());  //
            map.fitBounds(layer.getDefaultViewport()); 
        });
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/master/build/scripts/ng-map.js"></script>


<div ng-app="mapApp" ng-controller="mapCtrl">
  <ng-map center="21.876,-27.624" zoom="5" map-type-id="HYBRID" style="display:block; width: 100%; height:100%;">
    <kml-layer preserve-viewport="true" id="myLayer" url="http://googlemaps.github.io/js-v2-samples/ggeoxml/cta.kml"></kml-layer>
  </ng-map>
</div>
```